# Get html elements inside shadow root using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

I have example **HTML** code:

```
<section class="search-module">
    #shadow-root (open)
        <div class="app">
            <div class="title">Product Title</div>
        </div>
</section>
```

And with this code I can access to `shadow root` element parent container:

```
var searchModule = document.getElementsByClassName("search-module").item(0);
```

But can't get elements inside `shadow root` container using this command:

```
searchModule.getElementsByClassName("title") // undefined
```

Comment: The line: `searchModule.getElementsByClassName("title")` is working perfectly. Checked on JSBin

Comment: consider other methods to e.g. here: https://help.apify.com/en/articles/2619262-how-to-scrape-pages-with-shadow-dom (untested on my part..)

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).item is not a function`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to navigate to `shadow-root` first then you can get it:

```
const searchModule = document.querySelector('.search-module');
const searchModuleRoot = searchModule && searchModule.shadowRoot;

const title = searchModuleRoot.querySelector('.title');
```

Comment: Does not work for my case

Answer (score -1):

You can use QuerySelector for getting element inside the ShadowRoot

```
var searchModule = document.getElementsByClassName("search-module").item(0);
searchModule.querySelector('.title')
```